# Count unique records with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to produce a table that outputs a count of unique ID's for each day for separate regions. That is, there are three conditions:

1. Must match date;
2. Must match region;
3. Each ID is counted only once.

The table is in this format (only way bigger, with several appearances of each ID every day).  A virtual beer for any good advice.

[image]

Comment: So, I'm most of the way, its the unique count I can't get right.  So, I've got =COUNTIFS(sheet1!A:A, A3, D:D, "=Midlands") Need it to only count unique values though.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Thats kind of what I want but the pivot table doesn't give me the option to count unique items.

Comment: Hey Nick, Happy to help. Please update your question rather than posting your finding as an answer. If you think my answer addresses your question then please accept as answer (up vote if you like it :-D )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple. Use the in-built tool called Pivot table to do this task. To make Pivot table, Goto the Insert tab and select "Pivot table".
[image]
Enter the range of your table - like shown below - this is for my example
[image]

Now Click "OK". You will see a blank box.

The next thing to do is to add the fields are rows and columns as you want.  See the image below[image].

Just do the same thing for your data. You will have the desired result.
Important note: Under the values section, Excel will by default offer you the "SUM" of Vehicles. You need to click on the arrow next to it, select change field settings and select Count in the box that shows up - click ok.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Thats kind of what I want but the pivot table doesn't give me the option to count unique registrations.   So in the data I have, the same reg could appear 10 times on a day, I only want to count that once.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end... Thanks for the nudge in a different direction Prasanna.  Added an extra column to my data source and pivot tabled with that to show unique only count.

Kind of like this...

[image]